# aar file size of third party library inside android library project reducing to 0

Tags: android, android-library

I have created an android library project and included some third party libraries (aar files) in lib folder. When I am generating library project build, I checked during aar file analysis that it still contains all third party libraries in lib folder but their size is 0. I am also getting class not found exception for third party library classes.
I have tried both debug and release build.
I have added all dependencies as

> implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')

and then  also tried individual

> ```
> implementation files('libs/XXX.aar')
> implementation files('libs/XYZ.aar')
> implementation files('libs/ABC.aar')
> implementation files('libs/ABD.aar')
> implementation files('libs/ABE.aar')
> implementation files('libs/ABK.aar')
> ```
>
> [image]

Comment: Have you added the third party libraries as dependencies? A Quick way to check that in Android Studio is by opening the lib folder `Project View` and moving to **libs** folder. If you don't see a triangle before the aar file you haven't added the dependencies correctly in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I have added them as implementation and provided path of the libs folder. I have attached screenshot.

Comment: Is it; you can only access third party libs in this module and not in the module which depends on this module? Or you cannot access these third party libs in the module where you've added them as a dependency?

Comment: you are right, my deliverable is android library to the end client. I can't share third party libs with them individually.

Comment: Without looking at the problem itself, it'll be difficult to debug. Try changing `implementation` to `api`. And make sure you haven't downloaded/copied a corrupt version of **.aar** files.

Comment: Thanks guys for your effort, problem was somewhere else. There were some missing dependencies of the third party aar files in my gradle file which was causing crash. Although aar file analyzer is showing size as 0 but it's coping file somewhere

Comment: @Manish what was your exact solution to the problem? I'm facing similar issues.

Comment: Hi @dan, in my case, I had some missing dependencies of the aar file in library project. Secondly, its working fine in release mode but for debug mode, i have to use maven dependencies. In release mode, library project's dex file include all classes of the library.

Comment: @Manish I want to use an open GitHub project as.aar in my project instead of using dependency, I'm able to generate debug .aar of that 3rd party project and wanted to know can I generate release .aar?

Comment: @AsthaGarg you should check your build variant and select release instead of debug. You can also run ./gradlew assembleRelease task from command line or gradle task window.

Answer (score -2):

The lib that you created will be in a separate folder and not with the app source code. you will find the sharable lib there.

Project -> lib name -> build -> output -> aar -> {lib name}-release.arr

Comment: question is regarding third party library added in the library project which is creating aar file. I know its there in the build output folder

Comment: @Manish You can try putting the lib under the created libs. But I am not sure bundling arr files into a larger arr file is a good idea.

Comment: I think you mean to say inside lib folder of the app. Its not possible in my case. My output is aar file and we can't share other aar files to the end client.